# How to display all kinds of content in bootstrap modal in asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I receive `FileContentResult` as `byte[]` from a controller action. This file can be pdf, word document, any image format, or any gis file format. 
I need to display this file, regardless of its format, in a bootstrap modal, in an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.

Is there a way to do that without checking content type?

Comment: I doubt it, since in order to display the file, you must understand and be able to decode the content. Either your own code must do that decoding, or a 3rd party library - but in each case you have to understand which decoding algorithm to use. But a `FileContentResult` contains `ContentType` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.fileresult.contenttype?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_FileResult_ContentType) so you can use that to understand what kind of file it is, and what to use to try and display it.

Comment: Okay thank you @ADyson :)